# can i configure a subdomain to point to a specific path within a web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

i have my (spring) web application `'mywebapp'` configured in tomcat as follows:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml

<Context path="/mywebapp" docBase="<absolute path to my web application>" 
         debug="0" privileged="true" reloadable="true">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"                
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/> 
</Context>
```

on my local machine, i can access my application from browser at the following url:

`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/`

no issues whatsoever up to this point

to support mobile devices we have recently implemented a separate set of views which are organised under path `m/`. this mapping is done via spring's `@RequestMapping` annotation. basically, now there are two sets of resources that are served via the following urls:

`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/`

and

`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/m/`

where the former is for desktop / laptop users and the latter is for mobile users

now, is there a way that i can configure a subdomain to make this work? in other words, how can i configure tomcat so that requests to

`http://m.localhost:8080/mywebapp/`

are forwarded to

`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/m/`

please keep in mind that there is only a single web application. so both the urls should actually reach the same application `'mywebapp'`

i thought configuring an additional `Host` element in tomcat's server.xml would be the way to go. but i still couldn't figure out how it can be done

i am on a windows machine and have already added the following entry in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

`127.0.0.1       m.localhost`

Comment: [URLRewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) might be useful for you. You can rewrite based on user-agent string. But best way to handle this scenario is at user facing web server. Where such type of scenarios and configuration is already available. See if you can use Nginx or apache httpd as proxy for your app

Comment: @Sangram i suppose that's the way i will have to go unless there's a 'tomcat'-only approach out there. thanks for your input